# Can someone help me understand these parameters/arguments?

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have been given some code for a Binary Search Tree and tasked with adding some functionality to it. But first, I would really like to gain a better understanding of the parameters/function definition for one of the functions given to me. The code:

```
void printTree( ostream & out = cout ) const
{
    if( isEmpty( ) )
        out << "Empty tree" << endl;
    else
        printTree( root, out );
}
void printTree( BinaryNode *t, ostream & out ) const
{
    if( t != nullptr )
    {
        printTree( t->left, out );
        out << t->element << endl;
        printTree( t->right, out );
    }
}
```

First off, I don't get why there is a `const` after the parentheses at the end of the function declaration. Another thing that doesn't make sense to me is the first function declaration's parameters  `ostream & out = cout`. Why are the parameters = to something, I have never seen this. I do not understand what the `ostream & out` is referencing in general. Running `printTree()` with no arguments works just fine. Why does this work even though there is no function declaration for `printTree` with no arguments?

By the way, this is all in C++.

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: You are asking about basic C++ fundamentals that are covered in every C++ textbook. Before you were "given some code for a Binary Search Tree and tasked with adding some functionality", I presume you would've also been given sufficient material that teaches these concepts? Unfortunately, stackoverflow.com is not a replacement for a C++ textbook. If there's something in your textbook's explanation of these language features that's unclear, feel free to quote a brief excerpt and explain your question. You can find a link to popular C++ textbooks above, where you can find more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const` after function declaration means that it is safe to use this function for const object of your class. Such functions can't change any fields in your object.

`ostream & out` is a global object std::cout that control output to a stream buffer of implementation-defined type. In simple words this object helps you to print information in your console or file.

`ostream & out = cout` means that cout is default parameter that will be passed in the function.

Another example of that:

```
void printX(int x = 5)
{
    std::cout << x;
}
```

If you don't provide this function any parameter then it will use default parameter.

```
printX(10); \\ will print 10
printX(); \\ will print 5
```

`Why does this work even though there is no function declaration for printTree with no arguments?`
That's because this function will use cout to print out your tree.

`I do not understand what the ostream & out is referencing in general.`

You can't pass to a function a copy of cout (because it's copy constructor is disabled).

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped a lot.

Comment: "ostream & out is a global object std::cout" no. `ostream& out` can be any `ostream`, `std::cout` is the default parameter